# iTunes Connect statistics by iOS device

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am wondering if it's possible to get information on which iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod) my applications were downloaded?

Comment: Is this really some kind of mistery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously no one is looking for download statistics for their apps.

I have found the answer from Apple technician that as of now there is now way to drill-down to device level in statistics. But they are looking to implement this feature.
Also the iTc Mobile app is more powerful than web based instance.

Comment: 9 years later and they still haven't implemented the "drill-down" yet...

Answer (score 0):

You can either by building your own iTunes Connect app or using a third party like [AppFigures](https://appfigures.com).

Currently there is **no** way of getting this information from within iTunes Connect.

I'm also looking for iOS version stats, but can't find any anywhere.

Comment: I am already using AppAnnie which does all that things iTunesConnect should be supporting from day one.